# Transform array is not considering null returns

Tags: javascript

I want to transform an array in this way :

- false values become 0
- true values become 1
- null values rest null

I used this function :

```js
var arr = [true, false, false, true, true, null, null, null, null];

var result = $.map(arr, function (val, i) {
            if (val == false) {
                return 0
            } else if (val == true) {
                return 1
            } else {
            return null
            }
        });

$("#result").text(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result">
    
</div>
```

This function returns [1,0,0,1,1]; ....

What I want to have = [1,0,0,1,1,null,null,null,null];

Any Idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you read the $.map() doco? You can't use $.map() if you want to include null values in the resulting array.

Comment: Apparently not, since the documentation states that returning null removes the element.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed this part, thanks

Comment: to resolve the issue I've done this : return [null]

Comment: If you have found a solution to the answer, please provide it as a stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [jQuery `$.map()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map), only return values that are not null or undefined are included in the resulting array.

Use Javascript's [native array `.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead, because it *will* put null values in the new array.

(Older IE doesn't support the array `.map()` method, but given that you are using jQuery 2.x your code doesn't support older IE either.)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this very easy by using plain javascript `.map()`:

```
var arr = [true, false, false, true, true, null, null, null, null];

var result = arr.map(function (val, i) {
    if (val === false) {
        return 0;
    } else if (val === true) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});

console.log(result) // Array [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, null, null, null, null ]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation the $.map removes null values ...

to have null values we can use [null] instead  ...

```js
var arr = [true, false, false, true, true, null, null, null, null];

var result = $.map(arr, function (val, i) {
            if (val == false) {
                return [0]
            } else if (val == true) {
                return [1]
            } else {
            return [null]
            }
        });
```

Comment: Nice workaround. It didn't occur to me to do it like that. (You shouldn't need the square brackets around 1 and 0, though they won't hurt.)